# I cant figure out why its returning those values

Tags: java

```
public class OpCond {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
     int n = 10, p = 5, q = 10;
     n = p = q = 5;
     n += p += q;
     System.out.println("A : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);
     q = n < p ? n++ : p++;
     System.out.println("B : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);
     q = n > p ? n++ : p++;
     System.out.println("C : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);
```

This is the program when i run it i get q=10 (the second line ) and i cant figure out why
I did it on a paper and i got q=5 in the second line

Comment: did you learn debugging your program ?

Comment: Well, what did you try? You might want to learn about ternary conditions and also learn about operator `++`. You can also use a debugger to execute partially the code.

Comment: Which line you don't understand?

Comment: **You** need to explain what result you expected, and why. We can't read your mind.

Comment: int n = 10, p = 5, q = 10; is useless because the next line you override all the values to 5. Next line n = 15 , p = 10 , q =5 . And then the condition (if n is smaller than p, then use the value of n and then increase, otherwise use the value of p and then increase) q = 15 < 10 ? 15 : 10; q = 10. Because n++ increases the value after it has been used. Don't need to learn to debug, you need to learn to read the code and now what each sentence does. Also font use ?: use if-else if you are learning it is easier to follow.

Comment: This was an exercice i found i didnt write this

Comment: Ill write it for you in clear code to see if you can understand it better that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you traduct your code in a more comprehensive form, maybe you should understand :

Your code is equivalent of :

```
   public class OpCond {
          public static void main(String [] args) {
             int n = 10, p = 5, q = 10;
             //n = p = q = 5;
             n = 5;
             p =5;
             q=5;
             //n += p += q;
             p = p + q //so p = 10
             n = n + p //so n = 15

             //disp : A : n = 15 p = 10 q = 5
             System.out.println("A : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);

             //q = n < p ? n++ : p++;
             if (n<p) { //false here
                 q = n; 
                 n = n + 1; 
             }else{
                 q = p //q = 10
                 p = p + 1; // p = 11
             }

             //disp : B : n = 15 p = 11 q = 10
             System.out.println("B : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);


             //q = n > p ? n++ : p++;
             if (n>p) { //true here
                 q = n; //q=15
                 n = n + 1; // n = 16
             }else{
                 q = p
                 p = p + 1;
             }

             //disp : C : n = 16 p = 11 q = 15
             System.out.println("C : n = " + n + " p = " + p + " q = " + q);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After `n += p += q;` you already understand why we're getting the following to print:

```
A : n = 15 p = 10 q = 5
```

Now the question is why the second printing is:

```
B : n = 15 p = 11 q = 10
```

or in specific why `q = 10`.

The answer is because of this line:

```
q = n < p ? n++ : p++;
```

since n > p, q is assigned with the value of `p` (ternary operator), and the action `p++` is called "post-increment" which means that it happens only *after* the assignment (then p becomes 11).

Answer (score 0):

I can see what you mean from the output which is as follows

```
A : n = 15 p = 10 q = 5
B : n = 15 p = 11 q = 10
C : n = 16 p = 11 q = 15
```

q is 10 because

```
n += p += q;
```

this translates to `n = n + (p = p + q)`

in the next line 
q = n < p ? n++ : p++;

translates to `15 < 10 ? 15++ : 10++` (so 10 will be return to RHS and then the value of p will increment, hence q=10)